# Jquery dropdown menu flicker after mouseexit and mouseenter instantly again

Tags: jquery, delay

I've built a simple dropdown three tier using ul's and li's obviously. I've included a delay for it to open on hover using stop.().slideToggle(), so it doesnt open by mistake if hovered intentionally. the same I've done a delay for it to close, so if user hover out by mistake menu remains for a second giving time to hover back on it. prob is that once hovered back menu starts to flicker kind of open close randomly.

Code for menu to show up and close with delay below: 
    `// Show then hide ddown menu on hover
     $('.ddown').hover(function(){ 
         $( this ).children('ul').stop().delay(500).slideDown(500,'easeOutBounce');
    }, function() {
         $( this ).children('ul').stop().delay(1000).slideUp(500,'easeOutBounce');
    });`

Originally it was slide toggle, but now changed it to slide up and down, since I though on hover back again it was toggled and it would invoke the menu to close since it was still open in the delay..but no difference.

any help?

Thanks again as always!

Ian

Comment: A JSFiddle might make the problem and the solution easier to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your answer helped but didn't provide a solution to my issue. The solution can be found here: [UPDATED JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/natvk/1/) for anyone running into same issues, here's d code below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//Show then hide ddown menu on hover
$('.ddown').hover(function () {
    $(this).children('ul').stop(true).delay(500).slideDown(500);
}, function () {
    $(this).children('ul').stop(true).delay(1000).slideUp(500);
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

This might work, although I haven't tested it

```
var menu_animation_timeout = null;
$('.ddown').hover(function(){
        clearTimeout(menu_animation_timeout);
        menu_animation_timeout = setTimeout(function(){
            $( this ).children('ul').stop().slideDown(500,'easeOutBounce');
        }, 500) 

    }, function() {
        clearTimeout(menu_animation_timeout);   
        menu_animation_timeout = setTimeout(function(){
            $( this ).children('ul').stop().slideUp(500,'easeOutBounce');
        }, 1000)
    });
```

From the documentation, it looks like there is no way to cancel the `delay()`, so the `stop()` will only dequeue the currently running animation, but not the delayed animation, that is what is causing the flicker.

Comment: thanks for your answer will give it a try soon Yogesh!